# Android application crases when switching activity

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a problem with an Android aplication.  When I try to swich from main activity (PretvornikValut) to another one (Pretvornik) via buttun I get the "Unfortunately aplication stopped working" error. Can anyone help?

PretvornikValut.java

```
package pretvornik.valut;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;


public class PretvornikValut extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        View gumbPretvori = findViewById(R.id.gumb_pretvornik);
        gumbPretvori.setOnClickListener(this);

        View gumbTecaji = findViewById(R.id.gumb_tecaji);
        gumbTecaji.setOnClickListener(this);



    }
    public void sendMessage(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Pretvornik.class);
        startActivity(intent);

}
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.gumb_pretvornik:
                Intent i = new Intent(this, Pretvornik.class);
                //i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);                
                startActivity(i);           
                break;

                        case R.id.gumb_tecaji:
                Intent tecaj = new Intent(this, Tecaji.class);
                tecaj.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);              
                startActivity(tecaj);           
                break;

        }
}
}
```

Pretvornik java

```
package pretvornik.valut;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

/**
 *
 * @author FAKS
 */
public class Pretvornik extends Activity {

    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.pretvornik);
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#99CCCC"
        >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gumb_pretvornik"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Pretvornik"
        />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gumb_tecaji"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/OK"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Izpis tecajev"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Izberi zeljeno opcijo"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

pretvornik.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#99CCCC"
    >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="glavni program"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="pretvornik.valut"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="PretvornikValut"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

                    <activity
            android:name="Pretvornik"
            android:label="@string/Pretvornik_valut" > 
            <meta-data
            android:name="PretvornikValut"
            />           
  </activity>

  <activity
            android:name="Tecaji"
            android:label="@string/Izpis_tecajev" > 
            <meta-data
            android:name="PretvornikValut"
            />           
  </activity>



        </activity>




    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please post your logcat too.

Comment: try using `Intent intent = new Intent(Current_Activity.this, Your_otheractivity.class);` for starting new activity

Comment: Try to change the row `android:name="Pretvornik"` to `android:name=".Pretvornik"`! And show your logcat!

Answer (score 1):

Change your manifest xml,

add action for your activities

action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY"

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="pretvornik.valut"
        android:versionCode="1"
        android:versionName="1.0" >

        <uses-sdk
            android:minSdkVersion="8"
            android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

        <application
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

           <activity
                android:name="PretvornikValut"
                android:label="@string/app_name" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="Pretvornik"
                android:label="@string/hello_world" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY" />
            </activity>
            <activity
                android:name="Tecaji"
                android:label="@string/hello_world" >
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTIVITY" />            
            </activity>

        </application>

    </manifest>
```